# Serilog with .NET Core AWS Serverless Web API project

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, logging, asp.net-core, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an AWS Serverless API application which is built with .NET Core (2.1). I have set this up with Serilog logging which uses the AWS Cloudwatch sink for it's logging destination. This project depends on a shared class library which is where the core logic resides.

I have noticed that not all my logging messages are making it into Cloudwatch. Messages in my API Controllers do get logged succesfully but messages from the shared class library are only logged when I'm running locally, not when using the live API.

Here is my logging setup in Startup.

```
var awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(config["AWS:AccessKey"], config["AWS:SecretKey"]);
if (env.IsProduction())
{
    var options = new CloudWatchSinkOptions
    {
        LogGroupName = config["AWS:Cloudwatch:LogGroup"],
        LogStreamNameProvider = new LogStreamNameProvider(),
        TextFormatter = new Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter()
    };

    var client = new AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient(awsCredentials, RegionEndpoint.EUWest2);
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
        .WriteTo
        .AmazonCloudWatch(options, client)
        .CreateLogger();
}

services.AddSingleton(Log.Logger);
```

I've also tried adding `services.AddLogging(builder => builder.AddSerilog());` but that hasn't helped.

I am using it like this:

```
public class TestService
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public TestService(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void TestMethod()
    {
        this.logger.Information("Test Message");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `services.AddLogging(configuration => configuration.AddSerilog()).AddSingleton(Log.Logger);`?

Comment: Just tried. No luck :(

Comment: How are you passing `ILogger` to your service?  The default dependency injection container does not auto map the dependencies as it does in the controller.  You have to call your `ServiceProvider.GetService` to retrieve the dependency to manually pass unless you write that mapping yourself.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't set up anything for this. I thought ILogger would be injected like any other service would be? I don't want to have to do `ServiceProvider.GetService` every time I want to use the logger. Surely that goes against the point of dependency injection. Is there a way I can do this without `ServiceProvider.GetService`?

Comment: Also, I'm not getting any exceptions saying the DI has failed by the way. It's just refusing to log in a live environment.

Answer (score 1):

The default dependency injection framework has several limitations.  Inside of a controller the dependencies will automatically load via placement in the constructor.  However, in nested classes you have to pass the dependency itself, otherwise the framework will not automatically resolve.  The framework works under the presumption of a composition root.  In essence:

```
// Auto Resolved:
public class SampleController : Controller
{
     private readonly ILogger logger;

     public SampleController(ILogger logger) => this.logger = logger;

     public IActionResult Index()
     {
         logger.Information("...");
         ..
     }
}

// Will not auto resolve
public class SampleService
{
     private readonly ILogger logger;

     public SampleService(ILogger logger) => this.logger = logger;

     public void SampleAction()
     {
         logger.Information("...");
         ..
     }
}
```

For you to correctly implement the logger within the `SampleService` you would need to do something along these lines:

```
// Logger as property
Logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger>();
var sampleService = new SampleService(Logger);

// Called directly passed
var sampleService = new SampleService(serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger>());
```

That has been my experience, otherwise it will fail to use the defined implementation you passed.  There could be information I do not have that may also be affecting your code.

Comment: Is this specific to `ILogger`? I ask because I have services in my class library with many other dependencies which are all set up with DI and they work perfectly fine. The only thing I am having an issue with is `ILogger`, nothing else.

Comment: Honestly, I believe it may stem from their framework for DI more than ILogger implementation, but I could be mistaken.  I simply noticed that if at a root level some where a concrete instance is not passed then dependencies are not resolved further down the pipe.